How to customize rustfmt style with rust-analyzer
How do I get my lsp config in neovim to format my rust code in the desired style? How do I get it to follow what's prescribed in ~/.config/rustfmt/rustfmt.toml? Is my global rustfmt.toml incorrect or is my LSP config not using it like it should?
I have the latest rust-analyzer installed with Mason.
Here is my none-ls.lua:
return {
    "nvimtools/none-ls.nvim",
    config = function()
        local null_ls = require("null-ls")

        local eslint_d_path = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/mason/bin/eslint_d"

        null_ls.setup({
            sources = {
                null_ls.builtins.formatting.stylua,
                null_ls.builtins.formatting.prettier,
                null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.eslint_d.with({
                    command = eslint_d_path,
                    extra_args = { "--config", vim.fn.expand(vim.loop.cwd() .. "/eslint.config.mjs") },
                    condition = function(utils)
                        return utils.root_has_file("eslint.config.mjs")
                    end,
                }),
                null_ls.builtins.formatting.shfmt,
            },
        })

        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gf", vim.lsp.buf.format, {})
    end,
}

I prefer this formatting style:
pub fn run(address: &str) -> Result<Server, std::io::Error> {
    let server = HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .route("/health_check", web::get().to(health_check))
    })
    .bind(address)?
    .run();

    Ok(server)
}

but in my vim buffer if I hit <leader>gf (as in, vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gf", vim.lsp.buf.format, {}) defined in none-ls.lua). It reformats to:
pub fn run(address: &str) -> Result<Server, std::io::Error> {
    let server = HttpServer::new(|| App::new().route("/health_check", web::get().to(health_check)))
        .bind(address)?
        .run();

    Ok(server)
}

in lsp-config.lua (I'll add the entire file at the bottom as well):
lspconfig.rust_analyzer.setup({
  capabilities = capabilities,
  settings = {
    ["rust-analyzer"] = {
      cargo = {
        allFeatures = true,
        features = { "ssr" },
      },
      procMacro = {
        ignored = {
          leptos_macro = {
            -- "component", -- Uncomment if needed
            "server",
          },
        },
      },
      rustfmt = {
        overrideCommand = { "rustfmt", "--edition", "2018" },
        config = "~/.config/rustfmt/rustfmt.toml",
      },
    },
  },
})


and I have ~/.config/rustfmt/rustfmt.toml:
[general]
# Ensure that functions are formatted with a newline before the opening brace
fn_brace_style = "SameLineWhere"

[style]
# Use a compact style for closures
fn_call_style = "Visual"

lsp-config.lua
return {
    {
        "williamboman/mason.nvim",
        lazy = false,
        config = function()
            require("mason").setup()
        end,
    },
    {
        "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim",
        lazy = false,
        opts = {
            auto_install = true,
        },
    },
    {
        "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
        lazy = false,
        config = function()
            local capabilities = require("cmp_nvim_lsp").default_capabilities()

            local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")

            -- Ensure ESLint is setup
            lspconfig.eslint.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
                root_dir = lspconfig.util.root_pattern(
                    ".eslintrc",
                    ".eslintrc.js",
                    ".eslintrc.json",
                    ".eslintrc.yaml",
                    "eslint.config.mjs",
                    ".git"
                ),
                settings = {
                    workingDirectory = { mode = "auto" },
                },
            })

            lspconfig.tsserver.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
            })
            lspconfig.html.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
            })
            lspconfig.lua_ls.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
            })
            lspconfig.rust_analyzer.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
                settings = {
                    ["rust-analyzer"] = {
                        cargo = {
                            allFeatures = true,
                            features = { "ssr" },
                        },
                        procMacro = {
                            ignored = {
                                leptos_macro = {
                                    -- "component", -- Uncomment if needed
                                    "server",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        rustfmt = {
                            overrideCommand = { "rustfmt", "--edition", "2018" },
                            config = "~/.config/rustfmt/rustfmt.toml",
                        },
                    },
                },
            })
            lspconfig.sqlls.setup({
                root_dir = function(fname)
                    return vim.fn.getcwd()
                end,
                capabilities = capabilities,
            })
            lspconfig.taplo.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
            })
            lspconfig.emmet_language_server.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
                filetypes = {
                    "html",
                    "css",
                    "javascriptreact",
                    "typescriptreact",
                    "javascript",
                    "typescript",
                    "jsx",
                    "tsx",
                },
            })
            -- lspconfig.prisma_language_server.setup({
            --   capabilities = capabilities,
            -- })

            vim.keymap.set("n", "K", vim.lsp.buf.hover, {})
            vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>e", vim.diagnostic.open_float)
            vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>E", vim.diagnostic.setloclist)
            vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gd", vim.lsp.buf.definition, {})
            vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gr", vim.lsp.buf.references, {})
            -- vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>ca", vim.lsp.buf.code_action, {})
            -- vim.keymap.set("v", "<leader>ca", vim.lsp.buf.code_action, {})
            vim.keymap.set({ "n", "v" }, "<leader>ca", vim.lsp.buf.code_action, {})

            vim.keymap.set("n", "[d", vim.diagnostic.goto_prev)
            vim.keymap.set("n", "]d", vim.diagnostic.goto_next)
        end,
    },
}


I don't see those rustfmt configs in the official docs. Are you sure they exist?
